# heroku can't write data to mlab

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, mlab

I have a node express mongodb app that can run CRUD operations successfully on my local machine to mlab. I can see the item added in my mlab account. But when I push it out to heroku, I can see the website and can access everything else, but I cannot save data to mlab.  In the console log after a few seconds, I get 503 (Service Unavailable).

In heroku, I also installed the mlab mongodb add-on and tried the following code, but still cannot save.

heroku config:add NODE_ENV=production

This is my config.js.  (credentials have been removed for posting)

```js
exports.DATABASE_URL = process.env.DATABASE_URL ||
                       global.DATABASE_URL ||
                       (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
                       'mongodb://localhost/local-app':
 'mongodb://username:password@database.mlab.com:9999/databasename');
exports.PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

This is my server.js.

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config');
var Item = require('./models/item');

// Mongoose Connect
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

/* STEP 1 - creating objects and constructors*/
var runServer = function(callback) {
    mongoose.connect(config.DATABASE_URL, function(err) {
        if (err && callback) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        console.log("Connected to mongodb!");
        app.listen(config.PORT, function() {
            console.log('Listening on localhost:' + config.PORT);
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    });
};

if (require.main === module) {
    runServer(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
};

/* STEP 2 - api end points */
app.get('/items', function(req, res) {
    Item.find(function(err, items) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Internal Server Error'
            });
        }
        res.json(items);
    });
});

app.post('/items', jsonParser, function(req, res) {
    console.log("req:", req.body);

    if (!req.body) {
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    else {
        var favoritesList = req.body;
        res.status(201).json(favoritesList);
    }

    Item.create({
            name: req.body.name,
            wineResults: req.body.wineResults
        },

        function(err, item) {
            if (err) {
                //return res.sendStatus(500).json({
                message: err
                    //});
            }
            else {
                message: "done"
                    //res.sendStatus(200);
            }
        });
});


app.use('*', function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).json({
        message: 'Not Found'
    });
});

/* STEP 3 - server settings*/
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, process.env.IP);
exports.app = app;
exports.runServer = runServer;
```

Would appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this bit of code backwards? You're telling it that if it's in production, it should look to localhost? `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'mongodb://localhost/local-app': 'mongodb://username:password@database.mlab.com:9999/databasename'`

Comment: @Adam, I wasn't sure about the order of that.  I reversed it, but now the application won't start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your conditional logic has an error in it (in your `config.js`). Here's you current code:

```
exports.DATABASE_URL = process.env.DATABASE_URL ||
                       global.DATABASE_URL ||
                       (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
                       'mongodb://localhost/local-app':
 'mongodb://username:password@database.mlab.com:9999/databasename');
```

Here's what you should change it to:

```
exports.DATABASE_URL = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/local-app';
```

This will make your application behave as it should, eg:

- If running on localhost, no `MONGODB_URI` environment variable should be set, so your application will write to mongodb on localhost.
- If running on Heroku, you WILL have a `MONGODB_URI` environment variable, so you should use that database.

You don't need to do anything special with the `NODE_ENV` stuff for your database -- this should all be solved by your database environment variables alone.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but I'm still not able to save data.

Comment: If you run `heroku config` from the command line, do you see a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable listed there for your Mongo DB?

Comment: I see a url for BUILDPACK_URL and MONGODB_URI.  But no DATABASE_URL.

Comment: Ah, then you need to change the code to say `process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/local-app';` since you have no DATABASE_URL.

Comment: Thanks for updating the code, but if I use the updated code, the application won't start and I get Application Error.  It will only start up when I use my original code in config.js.

Comment: Can you paste your Heroku logs? I think the issue must be something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133676/discussion-between-marcusk7-and-rdegges).

Comment: rdegges was kind enough to work with me and pointed out that I was calling app.listen twice.  Once at the top of the server.js file and again at the bottom.